# How to know position of html element in Angular Form

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to get position in form when clicking the Add Field button that has (click)='getFormPosition'
On clicking that button I'd like to get position in form so in this case I'd like to get: (SaleToPOIRequest.DiagnosisRequest) or  SaleToPOIRequest => DiagnosisRequest.

I'm looking for a way to know in which form group am I and what groups are above it.

In the example bellow the button is in formGroup: DiagnosisRequest and above that there is SaleToPOIRequest. That's why the expected outcome is this :  SaleToPOIRequest.DiagnosisRequest or  SaleToPOIRequest => DiagnosisRequest.

```
<div class="request-form" formGroupName="SaleToPOIRequest">
      <div formGroupName="DiagnosisRequest">
        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>DiagnosisRequest</span>
            </td>
            <td class="form-buttons">
              <button color="primary" (click)='getFormPosition' mat-raised-button>Add Field</button>
              <button color="primary" mat-raised-button>Add Category</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>HostDiagnosisFlag</mat-label>
                <input formControlName="HostDiagnosisFlag" matInput>
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
</div>
```

And here is my ts in case your wondering:

```
public DiagnosisRequestForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  SaleToPOIRequest: new FormGroup({
      DiagnosisRequest: new FormGroup({
        HostDiagnosisFlag: new FormControl(''),
      }) 
   })
 })
```

Comment: [link] (https://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm) this might help.

Comment: What do you mean by you try to get position in form ? You would like to get the position of what ? From what ? To do what ? I didn't get you final goal. Give us more detail pls

Comment: @crg Thereis a div that has formGroupName="SaleToPOIRequest" and inside that div is another div with formGroupName="DiagnosisRequest" when calling a function by clicking the button I'd like to know where in form am I. So the expected outcome would give me SaleToPOIRequest => DiagnosisRequest or SaleToPOIRequest.DiagnosisRequest , I want to use this on multiple places so I need code that will somehow know the form groups above my the element  from which the function is called.

Comment: @satyen I don't want to know the position as in I guess pixels but position within a Form so I want to know all form groups above my element.

Comment: Ok, you want to get a form element's location in the DOM tree. _But why?_ Smells like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @msanford Because I need to add a formControl to my Form and that I  can do with: (this.SaleRequestForm.get("SaleToPOIRequest.DiagnosisRequest") as FormGroup).addControl("test", new FormControl()). I have many buttons like this in different formGroups so that's why I need to know my position in Form otherwise I cannot add the Control to a specific form group in which the button is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have answer to this question, frankly because I don't think it's possible to do it in a clean way.

So the solution for me was to rework it whole and do it recursively so that adding another formControl/group would be easier and done in TS, after that just update or generate the whole html again.

Here are questions that reference the problem of generating it recursively:

[Generate form trough loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420469/generate-form-trough-loop)

[Generate table from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369157/generate-table-from-form)

Answer (score -1):

```
// you can use an id on div with DiagnosisRequest
 in JS
var el = document.getElementById('DiagnosisRequest')
window.alert(el.offsetLeft)
//for X,Y position
const elbc = el.getBoundingClientRect()
window.alert(elbc.x+" "+elbc.y) 

//if you are using ts and angular 
@ViewChild("DiagnosisRequest", { static: false }) dr: ElementRef;

//then you can get this.dr.nativeElement.offsetLeft
```

Comment: Using and id on an element is very inefficient I have a lot of these buttons so if  I wanted them to all work I'd have to add a lot of ids. I'm looking for a better solution that I can use anywhere.

Comment: Also I'm not looking for pixel positino or anything like that but position inside my form.