# Generate form trough loop

Tags: angular, forms, loops

Im trying to generate a form group by loop so I have some input and based on that it will create a form with nested group. My thought of aproaching it was this:

```
public transactionOrRefundRequestForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

this.transactionOrRefundRequestForm.addControl('SaleToPos', new FormGroup(
      this.generateForm(this.formStructure)
    ));


 public generateForm(formEntry: FormEntry[] | null | undefined): any {

  formEntry.forEach(fe => {
    console.log(fe);
    console.log(this.transactionOrRefundRequestForm.controls);

    if (fe instanceof FormCategory) {
      const fc = fe as FormCategory;

     return {fc.name : new FormGroup(this.generateForm(fc.entries))};
    }

    if (fe instanceof FormInput || FormInputSelect || FormInputBoolean) {
      const fi = fe as FormInput;
 
      return {fi.name: new FormControl('')};
    }

  });
```

}

So when I get input it will cycle trough it and if it's input it will return new formControl but if it's category it will return new FormGroup with children that will be looped again by the function.

Right now my result is an empty form but i'm not really sure what am I. doing wrong.

Here is a stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqndkq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

It throws error for the class with no constructor but for me it works just fine. Sooooo I don't know what to do there, sorry.

Comment: Can you share stackblitz link here  ? and add code your there too

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqndkq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: your code has compilation issues and you are asking multiple things at the same, please improve your question to get better answers

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Yes it has compilation issues but they don't make sense because it is asking for a constructor even tough there is one. Also I don't see where I' m asking multiple things at once but either way I'll try to improve it.

Comment: That "constructor error" is because you are not closing the previous class before creating the new one `class FormEntry` on line 164 of `app.component.ts`, that is one of the reasons I recommended that you have separate files for each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also partly contains solution for question [Generate table from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369157/generate-table-from-form)

So I managed to generate it recursively and this is how, the code is a bit longer so if you get lost reply to me and I will try to edit this and clarify it better:

So first generate your default form structure.

Mine looks like this:

```
this.formStructure =
      new FormCategory(
        'SaleToPOIRequest',
        [
          new FormCategory(
            'AdminRequest',
            [
              new FormInput('ServiceIdentification', '', [Validators.required]),
            ])
        ]);
```

Then the logic:

After generating default form I `this.reconstructForm();`

```
 private reconstructForm(): void {
    const oldValue = this.rebootRequestForm.value;
    this.rebootRequestForm = new FormGroup({});
    this.generateFormBranch(this.rebootRequestForm, [this.formStructure]);
    this.rebootRequestForm.patchValue(oldValue);
  }
```

That will trigger `this.generateFormBranch()`

```
public generateFormBranch(parent: FormGroup, structure: FormEntry[]) {
    structure.forEach(formEntry => {
      if (formEntry instanceof FormInput) {
        parent.addControl(this.toInput(formEntry).name,
          new FormControl(this.toInput(formEntry).defaultValue, this.toInput(formEntry).validation));
      }
      if (formEntry instanceof FormCategory) {
        const formGroup = new FormGroup({});
        this.generateFormBranch(formGroup, formEntry.entries);
        if (formEntry.parent) {
          parent.addControl(formEntry.name, formGroup);
        } else {
          this.rebootRequestForm.addControl(formEntry.name, formGroup);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

This will generate the form for me and I can add Category and Input like this:

```
public addCategory(parent: FormCategory): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FormUpdateDialogComponent, {
      data: <FormUpdateDialogComponent> {
        dialogType: 'category',
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.checkAndAddFormControl(parent, data, FormCategory);
      });
  }

  public addInput(parent: FormCategory): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FormUpdateDialogComponent, {
      data: <FormUpdateDialogComponent> {
        dialogType: 'input',
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.checkAndAddFormControl(parent, data, FormInput);
      });
  }
```

both will trigger: `this.checkAndAddFormControl()`

```
checkAndAddFormControl(parent: FormCategory, name: string, type) {
    let isAvailable = true;
    parent.entries.forEach(entry =>
      entry.name === name ? isAvailable = false : isAvailable);

    if (type === FormInput) {
      if (isAvailable && name !== '') {
        parent.addEntry(new FormInput(name, '', []));
        this.reconstructForm();
        this.snackBar.open('Input ' + name + ' has been added at top of the category', 'OK');
      } else {
        this.snackBar.open('Name has already been set or it\'s null', 'OK');
      }
    }

    if (type === FormCategory) {
      if (isAvailable && name !== '') {
        parent.addEntry(new FormCategory(name, []));
        this.reconstructForm();
        this.snackBar.open('Category ' + name + ' has been added at the bottom of the category', 'OK');
      } else {
        this.snackBar.open('Name has already been set or it\'s null', 'OK');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operator instead of forEach, If we return anything inside [forEach](http://%5BforEach%5D%5B1%5D) it does not return anything,it will return only undefied.

```
public generateForm(formEntry: FormEntry[] | null | undefined): any {

  return formEntry.map(fe => {
    console.log(fe);
    console.log(this.transactionOrRefundRequestForm.controls);

    if (fe instanceof FormCategory) {
      const fc = fe as FormCategory;

     return {fc.name : new FormGroup(this.generateForm(fc.entries))};
    }

    if (fe instanceof FormInput || FormInputSelect || FormInputBoolean) {
      const fi = fe as FormInput;
 
      return {fi.name: new FormControl('')};
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: `fi.name : new FormControl`, it seems like the ":" should be a "," right ? see my answer bellow

Comment: Hi @MauricioGraciaGutierrez  I think since fi.name is dynamic value it should be something like this [fi.name] : new FormControl

Comment: well I copy pasted your code to the stackblitz and it has syntax errors

Comment: I tried using this but it gave me a {}. :/

Comment: Then I think you program have some other issue can you fix the stack blitz example?

Comment: fc.name wont work inside {} is there any solution to that?

Comment: Also I don't know how to fix the stackblitz because is says the class needs a constructor even tough it has one and same code works completely fine in my webstorm.

Comment: can you try this: {[fc.name]:new FormControl('')}

Comment: I achieved my wanted result with return new FormGroup(this.generateForm(fc.entries)); But not completely because this way the form groups added will not have names. When I tried return {[fc.name]: new FormGroup(this.generateForm(fc.entries))};  it seems to accept the name but for some reason it doesn't add it to the form like the return new FormGroup(this.generateForm(fc.entries)); does. I pretty sure it's those {} but you cannot do it without them so thats where I'm stuck currently. I really don't get why it doesn't add it when is wrapped in {}. When console logging it looks just fine.

Comment: What's is the issue when you do {[fc.name]: new FormGroup(this.generateForm(fc.entries))} like this. Are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error it just doesn't work for some reason. I get empty controls in the form. But when I use the first one I've told you about I get all the controls/groups but with no names. (Their names are indexes).  Here are pictures: https://ibb.co/7Q7PMLP   https://ibb.co/xMy8VMm

Comment: It's beacuse generateForm method returns array of formGroup or FormControl based on the conditions, generateForm should return object